# Ideal gas data needed

Tags: data

I want to do a quick computation in R that involves estimating the ideal gas constant from experimental data.  Ideally I'd have data from a monatomic gas at different pressures, volumes, temperatures and moles (or just pressure and volume, keeping the others fixed).  Anyone have an idea of where I might find a data set like this?  An R data frame would be nice, but I'll take excel, tab delimited, or whatever.

Comment: Search Google for datasets rather than SE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The National Institute of Standards and Technology (NIST) has ideal gas datasets [here](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/nist-computational-chemistry-comparison-and-benchmark-database-srd-101)